# Why Background isn't updating after calling function to Update it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently try to modify body's background depending some values of a stored ajax response. But when calling the function getBackground(); it isn't updating background and I don't understand why ? I would appreciate any help,

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  // Ajax call

  var responseWeather = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
    url:  urlLatLong,
    dataType: "json", 
    async: false
}).responseText);


  function getBackground(){
  var  n = new Date();
  var    hour = n.getHours();


  if (hour > 6 && hour < 18) {
      //response from Ajax
  if (responseWeather.weather[0].main === 'Rain') {     
   $('body').css('background-image', "https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-FRc-pTtmDaE/VESPnFw7e2I/AAAAAAABSIw/g_YMwPEPvRQ/s0/Rain%2BDrops%2BWindow%2BUHD.jpg");
 }else if (responseWeather.weather[0].main === 'Clouds') {
   $('body').css('background-image', "http://wallpapersonthe.net/wallpapers/b/3840x2400/3840x2400-sky_nature_cloudy_day_in_the_alpine_jungle_cloud_mountain_jungle-30477.jpg");
 }else if (responseWeather.weather[0].main === 'Clear') {
    $('body').css('background-image', "https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/sun_light_beams_meadow_glade_summer_day_53997_3840x2400.jpg");
 }
  }else{

    if (responseWeather.weather[0].main === 'Rain') {
   $('body').css('background-image', 'https://images3.alphacoders.com/279/279307.jpg');
 }else if (responseWeather.weather[0].main === 'Clouds') {
   $('body').css('background-image', 'http://www.walldevil.com/wallpapers/a68/night-background-cloudy-wallpaper-animated-skies-sky-wallpapers-art.jpg');
 }else if (responseWeather.weather[0].main === 'Clear') {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/c6/28/0e/c6280e8f909cdaa96f599f4b611e876c.jpg');
     }
    }
 }
 getBackground();


});
```

Comment: Hi. Are there any errors in the console ? And where is responseWeather from please?

Comment: just updated it, it is the stored response from an Ajax call.

Comment: Ok thanks - so could you post a sample of the JSON you receive, because if for example `responseWeather.weather[0].main === "sunshine"` then that would explain what you see. You have an if with no catch-all else clause.

Comment: Here is the complete script, html and css: http://codepen.io/ontiverosvzla/pen/WReVmp?editors=0011

Comment: Yes I understand and actually I was logging the response from responseWeather and for example it was 'Clouds' but it is not setting the background that should be set.

Comment: Ok - simple Ajax misunderstanding. Javascript execution does NOT pause whilst the code for the $.ajax() function runs. Google for tutorials on using Ajax and you will see that you need to use either a success callback or a promise (more modern). Its not complicated but too much to explain here.

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: How did you get on?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to wrap the image url into `url()`.

```
$('body').css('background-image', "url(https://...)");
```